# Should the amount of reputation gained and lost be proportional to your actual reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, voting

The amount of reputation lost and gained are fixed numbers instead of percentages. This isn't entirely fair for everyone.

For example, a down-vote subtracts 2 reputation from you. To new users, -2 reputation is a lot. To experienced users with lots of reputation, -2 reputation isn't much at all. Users with a lot of reputation can receive a lot of down-votes, and it won't hurt them so much. On the contrary, someone who just joined SE might get a down-vote, and it'll really hurt their reputation.

Let's say there's a user named John, and he has 10,000 reputation. If he receives 30 flags for spam and 100 down-votes, that's only losing ~7% of his reputation. That'd instantly kill Mary, who has just 150 reputation.

Reputation gained is unfair too. An up-vote on an answer gives you 10 reputation. To new users, +10 reputation is fantastic. To experienced users with lots of reputation, +10 barely affects them at all. Users with very low reputation can get a single up-vote, and their reputation is nearly doubled. However, users with a lot of reputation have to work very hard just to earn a ~10% increase in reputation.

To make Stack Exchange a bit more fair for all users, the the reputation rewards and penalties should scale based on your actual reputation.

For instance, a down-vote cast on a user with 100 reputation would be around -1, and a down-vote cast on a user with 1000 reputation would be around -5 or -10.

Comment: Why? You're posting all these feature requests with no real explanation

Comment: To make it more fair. Users with a ton of rep can get down-votes and flags and stuff and they still have 1000+ rep so they think, "Oh that was nothing."

Comment: Why is "fair" a good thing here? How do you judge fair? Why is the current system not fair?

Comment: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259072/should-there-be-a-grace-period-before-you-can-down-vote?noredirect=1#comment844517_259072!

Comment: What's that got to do with this?

Comment: You seem to also ignore that people who have +1000 rep **earned it**. It didn't just happen.

Comment: Just to make sure that 2k-3k+ people can't spam and post low-quality answers, and still have lots of rep.

Comment: People who have 2k-3k+ reputation are very unlikely to spam. And if they post low-quality they deserve downvotes - if you think they don't take downvotes seriously, I can tell you you are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of a vote doesn't change with the reputation of the user. The value of a good question or a good answer also doesn't change with the author's reputation.

With that in mind, scaling the rewards and penalties isn't in any way an improvement.